# JS regexp exclude matching based on set of chars

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a JS RegExp that will match word based on the exclusion of set chars: `[', ", -, _ ]` so **bolded** words should be matched only from my example:

**Milan** some word, **milan** again.**Milan** word - again: **Milan**, milan-milan. Milan-word **milan** is word.**milan** mialn . milan's milan"s, **milan** milan_milan.

Note: I don't want to include spaces, dots, commas, before/after word **milan** and therefore I need to get result same as I bolded it above.

I need it to work like:
**\bmilan\b**
but i need to exclude set of chars so it doesn't match examples like **milan-milan** and **milan's** at all.

I tried to make it work: https://regex101.com/r/FGeNlQ/1 but it isn't complete. In this example spaces, dots, etc... are included in matched word and I don't want that.

Sorry if this may be duplicate but i just can't find right answer

**EDIT**:

code usage:

```
window.wrapText = (sentence, word, description) ->
    regex = "(?:[^\"'`_-]|^)\\b(" + word + ")\\b(?![\"'`_-])"
    re = new RegExp(regex, 'gi')
    span = document.createElement('span')
    span.innerHTML = sentence

    Array.from span.childNodes, (node) =>
      if node.nodeType == 3
        node.nodeValue.split(re).forEach (part, i) ->
          add = undefined
          if i % 2
            add = document.createElement('span')
            add.textContent = part
            add.setAttribute('class', 'glossary_text')
          else
            add = document.createTextNode(part)
          span.insertBefore add, node

        span.removeChild node

    span.innerHTML
```

note: i may have not escaped well 'regex' variable

Comment: [`(?:[^"'\`_-]|^)\b(milan)\b(?!["'\`_-])`](https://regex101.com/r/3S0uhH/1) should be enough. Add necessary logic to get the capturing group 1 values.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes but this will include , and spaces in front of word

Comment: It does not matter if anything is "included", the structure of the match object provides enough details for you to write custom post-processing logic, which we cannot you help with as you have not shared any further details about what you are doing (replacing, extracting, wrapping....). Also, please post your code if you need help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i am trying to find that word and wrap in new tag, so that is reason why i dont to wrap <span>.Milan</span> but just <span>Milan</span>

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i posted this question which u marked as duplicate even if it is not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46816258/js-regexp-finding-word-that-is-not-in-tag-and-replace-string
i am trying to exclude specific <span> tag with specific class.

Comment: Please post the code you have now. Other question details are irrelevant.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok i will edit question