# Is there any way to outout blank as &nbsp; in lxml or other python xml lib?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

my code is:

```
>>> from lxml.html import tostring, HtmlElement
>>> a = HtmlElement()
>>> a.tag = "div"
>>> a.text = " "
>>> tostring(a)
b'<div> </div>'
```

Is there any way to output like in lxml or other python xml library?

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: There would be multiple ways. Do you want to replace all `" "`s with `&nbsp;`s? Or certain ones? If you do, you can just use `str`'s `replace` method.

Comment: I want to replace all space with &nbsp; str.replace can not work well in <div class="xxx"> 
 </div> case, it will replace the space between attribute and change the xml structure.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46816258/js-regexp-finding-word-that-is-not-in-tag-and-replace-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by replace blank to '\xa0' (160 is `&nbsp;` ascii code)